# Perl Manipulate a file to combine fragments found in the same group

Tags: perl, hash

I have this data set of fragments and positions that are classified into groups :

```
>Group 1
 fragmentA_6
 fragmentA_5
>Group 2
 fragmentA_3
 fragmentA_4
>Group 3
 fragmentA_1
 fragmentA_2
 fragmentB_1
```

and am trying to figure out a way to combine the fragments within their own groups while also changing the global position. A desired output of the above would look something like this.

```
>Group 1
 wholeA_3_[5,6]
>Group 2
 wholeA_2_[3,4]
>Group 3
 wholeA_1_[1,2]
 wholeB_1_[1]
```

As you can see fragmentA was present in group 1 and 2 more than once. In the output, the lowest position was re-adjusted (not for the first) and all members of that fragment are displayed in the brackets.

My data structure would look something like this

```
    $HoH { $fragment_id }{'POSITION'}[$pos-1] = $pos;
    $HoH { $fragment_id }{'GROUP'}[$pos-1]  = $group_id;
```

To compare fragments and groups I am using a loop like this :

```
my $rHoH = \%HoH;

foreach my $id (keys %HoH){
    for (my $i=0; $i < scalar(@{$rHoH->{$id}->{'POSITION'}}); $i++){
                    for (my $j = $i+1; $j < scalar(@{$rHoH->{$id}->{'POSITION'}}); $j++) {

                      #logic that will produce desired output here;
                      my $group_a = $rHoH->{$id}->{'GROUP'}[$i];
                      my $group_b = $rHoH->{$id}->{'GROUP'}[$j];
                         if($group_a == $group_b){

                         }
                   }
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how to approach this or is there an easier data structure I just can't think of. (still a novice).

Comment: Where does the 3 in `wholeA_3_[5,6]` come from?

Comment: The 3 is the re-adjusted position and the [5,6] is what the fragment position used to be. Since I am combining the fragments if I do not re-adjust the position for each of the wholeA, parts of the location would be skewed across groups. wholeA_3_[5,6] just happens to be the 3rd grouping of fragments for that id (wholeA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't fully understand what you mean by "re-adjusting the position", but this produces output similar to the one you wanted, but the numbering of the groupings is different (1, 2, 3 instead of 3, 2, 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %groups;
my $group;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>Group (\d+)/) {
        $group = $1;
    } else {
        ++$groups{$group}{$_};
    }
}

my %fragment_pos;

for my $group (sort keys %groups) {
    print ">Group $group\n";
    my %fragments;
    for my $fragment (keys %{ $groups{$group} }) {
        my ($id, $number) = $fragment =~ /(\w)_([0-9]+)/;
        $fragments{$id}{$number} = 1;
    }
    for my $id (sort keys %fragments) {
        ++$fragment_pos{$id};
        print " whole$id\_$fragment_pos{$id}_[";
        print join ',', sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $fragments{$id} };
        print "]\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I reworked the input data so I do not have to worry about the fragment pos but this helped me get to what I needed after changing a few things.